# Mocking Files In Python Unittest In Imported Modules

Tags: python, python-unittest, configparser, python-mock

I readily admit to going a bit overboard with unit testing. 
While I have passing tests, I find my solution to be inelegant, and I'm curious if anyone has a cleaner solution.

The class being tested:

```
class Config():

    def __init__(self):
        config_parser = ConfigParser()
        try:
            self._read_config_file(config_parser)
        except FileNotFoundError as e:
            pass

        self.token = config_parser.get('Tokens', 'Token', )

    @staticmethod
    def _read_config_file(config):
        if not config.read(os.path.abspath(os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ROOT_DIR, CONFIG_FILE))):
            raise FileNotFoundError(f'File {CONFIG_FILE} not found at path {BASE_DIR}{ROOT_DIR}')
```

The ugly test:

```
class TestConfiguration(unittest.TestCase):

    @mock.patch('config.os.path.abspath')
    def test_config_init_sets_token(self, mockFilePath: mock.MagicMock):
        with open('mock_file.ini', 'w') as file: #here's where it gets ugly
            file.write('[Tokens]\nToken: token')
        mockFilePath.return_value = 'mock_file.ini'

        config = Config()

        self.assertEqual(config.token, 'token')
        os.remove('mock_file.ini') #quite ugly
```

EDIT: What I mean is I'm creating a file instead of mocking one. 
Does anyone know how to `mock` a file object, while having its data set so that it reads ascii text? The class is deeply buried.
Other than that, the way `ConfigParser` sets data with `.read()` is throwing me off. Granted, the test "works", it doesn't do it nicely.

For those asking about other testing behaviors, here's an example of another test in this class:

```
@mock.patch('config.os.path.abspath')
def test_warning_when_file_not_found(self, mockFilePath: mock.MagicMock):
    mockFilePath.return_value = 'mock_no_file.ini'

    with self.assertRaises(FileNotFoundError):
        config.Config._read_config_file(ConfigParser())
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: That doesn't seem unreasonable. For a different solution, couldn't you just make `BASE_DIR`, `ROOT_DIR`, and `CONFIG_FILE` something that you can set in the module before instantiating a `Config()` instance? What if your `Config` class accepted as an optional parameter  a path to a configuration file?

Comment: I don't think you should be testing `ConfigParser`. You should rather be testing that `_read_config_file` does what you mean it to do which is, read a configuration file and raise an exception when it fails to do that.

Comment: Thanks, @larsks. I see the utility in that, too, but, for now, I'm interested in keeping all of my config-relevant info in one place (i.e., keep the name of the `.ini` file in the `.ini` file). What's really giving me trouble, here, is how the `ConfigParser` class sets file information when it calls `.read`. I'd rather just patch a mocked file object that takes ascii chars to set data, but the way the class is designed doesn't make that intuitive.

Comment: @OluwafemiSule - I did test that, as well, with several variants of the above as follows:

`with self.assertRaises(FileNotFoundError):`
            `config.Config._read_config_file(config.ConfigParser())` 

*(weird syntax to get around the hidden method prefix)

Comment: *typo above, (i.e., keep the name of the .ini file in the **Config** file)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found it!

I had to start off with a few imports:`from io import TextIOWrapper, BytesIO`

This allows a file object to be created: `TextIOWrapper(BytesIO(b'<StringContentHere>'))`

The next part involved digging into the `configparser` module to see that it calls `open()`, in order to `mock.patch` the behavior, and, here we have it, an isolated unittest!

```
@mock.patch('configparser.open') 
def test_bot_init_sets_token(self, mockFileOpen: mock.MagicMock):

    mockFileOpen.return_value = TextIOWrapper(BytesIO(b'[Tokens]\nToken: token'))

    config = Config()

    self.assertEqual(config.token, 'token')
```